# Ruby Unzip String

Tags: ruby, zip

I have to work with a zipped (*regular Zip*) string in Ruby.
Apparently I can't save a temporary file with [Ruby-Zip](http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/) or [Zip-Ruby](https://bitbucket.org/winebarrel/zip-ruby/wiki/Home).

Is there any practicable way to unzip this string?

Answer (score 8):

[rubyzip](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip) [supports StringIO since version 1.1.0](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip/blob/master/Changelog.md#110)

```
require "zip"
# zip is the string with the zipped contents
Zip::InputStream.open(StringIO.new(zip)) do |io|
  while (entry = io.get_next_entry)
    puts "#{entry.name}: '#{io.read}'"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

See [Zip/Ruby `Zip::Archive.open_buffer(...)`](https://bitbucket.org/winebarrel/zip-ruby/wiki/Home#!modifying-zip-data-in-memory):

```ruby
require 'zipruby'
Zip::Archive.open_buffer(str) do |archive|
  archive.each do |entry|
    entry.name
    entry.read
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As the Ruby-Zip seems to lack support of reading/writing to IO objects, you can fake File.
What you can do is the following:

1. Create a class called File under Zip module which inherits from StringIO, e.g. class Zip::File < StringIO
2. Create the exists? class method (returns true)
3. Create the open class method (yields the StringIO to the block)
4. Stub close instance method (if needed)
5. Perhaps it'll need more fake methods

Comment: I'm gonna check on thas as soon as possible!

Comment: The prober way would be, of course, to extend the Ruby-Zip library.

Answer (score 0):

As @Roman mentions, rubyzip currently lacks reading and writing of IO objects (including `StringIO.new(s)`).  Try using [zipruby](https://bitbucket.org/winebarrel/zip-ruby/wiki/Home) instead, like this:

```
gem install zipruby

require 'zipruby'

# Given a string in zip format, return a hash where 
# each key is an zip archive entry name and each
# value is the un-zipped contents of the entry
def unzip(zipfile)
  {}.tap do |h|
    Zip::Archive.open_buffer(zipfile) do |archive|
      archive.each {|entry| h[entry.name] = entry.read }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

The zlib library. Works fine with StringIO.