# unzipping a zip archive from a string

Tags: ruby, zip, stringio, rubyzip

I have a zip archive in a string, but the rubyzip gem appears to want input from a file.  The best I've come up with is to write the zip archive to a tempfile for the sole purpose of passing the filename to `Zip::ZipFile.foreach()`, but this seems tortured:

```
require 'zip/zip'
def unzip(page)
  "".tap do |str|
    Tempfile.open("unzip") do |tmpfile|
      tmpfile.write(page)
      Zip::ZipFile.foreach(tmpfile.path()) do |zip_entry|
        zip_entry.get_input_stream {|io| str << io.read}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a simpler way?

NOTE: See also [Ruby Unzip String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871498/ruby-unzip-string).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Zip/Ruby `Zip::Archive.open_buffer(...)`](https://bitbucket.org/winebarrel/zip-ruby/wiki/Home#!modifying-zip-data-in-memory):

```ruby
require 'zipruby'
Zip::Archive.open_buffer(str) do |archive|
  archive.each do |entry|
    entry.name
    entry.read
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks -- that works well!  See my complete answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/14912237/558639

Answer (score 0):

@maerics's answer introduced me to the zipruby gem (not to be confused with the rubyzip gem).  It works well.  My complete code ended up like this:

```
require 'zipruby'

# Given a string in zip format, return a hash where 
# each key is an zip archive entry name and  each
# value is the un-zipped contents of the entry
def unzip(zipfile)
  {}.tap do |entries|
    Zip::Archive.open_buffer(zipfile) do |archive|
      archive.each do |entry|
        entries[entry.name] = entry.read
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Ruby's [StringIO](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html) would help in this case.

Think of it as a string/buffer you can treat like an in-memory file.

Comment: I know all about StringIO.  I don't think Zip::ZipFile can handle a StringIO object, though I'd be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: it requires filename. not a stream-like object