# Logstash un-gzip array log configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

everyone!
I have logstash config, which forwards logs from RabbitMQ to elasticSearch. Something like this:

```
input {
    rabbitmq {
        ...
    }
}

filter {
    if [type] == "rabbitmq" {
        json {
            source => "message"
            target => "message"
        }
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["${ES_HOST}"]
    user => "${ES_USERNAME}"
    password => "${ES_PASSWORD}"
    sniffing => false
    index => "kit_events-%{[message][elasticsearch][index]}"
  }
}
```

And we were forced to compress logs on a fly, because they are spending too much traffic.
Logs were moved into array and gzipped.
What is the correct way of configuring un-gzipping and splitting array back into objects?

I did some research and found out that there is gzip_lines plugin and something on Ruby(?) to parse array, but I failed to implement it. Did anyone make something like this before?

UPD:

Added this filter

```
filter {

  if [type] == "kitlog-rabbitmq" {
    ruby {
      init => "
        require 'zlib'
        require 'stringio'
      "
      code => "
        body = event.get('[http][response][body]').to_s
        sio = StringIO.new(body)
        gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(sio)
        result = gz.read.to_s
        event.set('[http][response][body]', result)
      "
    }
  }
}
```

And now catching an error

```
ERROR][logstash.filters.ruby    ] Ruby exception occurred: not in gzip format
[DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] output received {"event"=>{"@timestamp"=>2018-11-30T09:16:19.127Z, "tags"=>["_rubyexception"], "@version"=>"1", "message"=>"x^\\x8B\\xAEV*\\xCE\\xCE\\xCC\\xC9)V\\xB2R\\x88V\\xD26T07\\xB7\\xB0\\xB4\\xB44000W\\x8A\\xD5QPJ\\xCE\\xCF+IL.\\u0001\\xCA*)\\u0001\\xB9\\xA9\\xB9\\x89\\x999 N\\x96C\\x96^r~.X,\\xA5\\u0014(R\\xADT\\x9A\\u000E6#\\xA0\\xB2$#?\\u000F\\xAC\\xB9\\u0000\\\"\\xE2\\u001C\\xAC\\u0014[\\v\\xE4\\xE6%概\\xF4z\\u0001\\xE9b%\\xA0\\xC8\\xC0\\xD9\\u001D\\v\\u0000\\u0003\\x9ADk", "type"=>"kitlog-rabbitmq"}}
```

Was trying different gzipping methods, but result is still the same. Also tried changing input codecs (plain - utf-8, plain - binary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the content in rabbitmq is gzipped?

In the best of all possible worlds, logstash would see the `content-encoding` header and unzip it for you, but the [plugin](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-rabbitmq) doesn't seem to do anything with that knowledge.  You might [request](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-rabbitmq/issues) the feature.

The plugin does let you access the header, so you could do the gzip yourself.  Something like this:

```
filter {
  if [@metadata][rabbitmq_properties][content-encoding] == "gzip" {
    ruby {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Examples of unzipping a string with ruby [exist elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871498/ruby-unzip-string).  Hopefully the 'zip' gem is available in logstash.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try!